# Simple Li Ion integrated Charger and balancer

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, cell-balancing

I am currently working on a project, which should contain a Li-Ion battery pack in the form of 8 18650 cells in 4S2P. 
The main consumers of the build are a class D amplifier and a single board computer, probably a Banana Pi Zero.

I would like to have a charger and balancer circuit integrated in the project, which would ideally be controllable in some form by the SBC. A charging voltage from 16V DC (or higher if needed) would be supplied by a power jack.

I have looked for charging and balancing ICs, the only suitable one I found, is the BG24702/3 from TI. It could handle the charging, but requires a huge amount of external circuitry.

Other ICs I’ve found, are only offered in QFN packages or similar. But I want to be able to solder everything by hand

Do you know a good and/or simple method for charging and/or balancing?
Is it possible to get a simple CC/CV power source and then charge and balance periodically?

Comment: Are you going to mass produce this or is it a one off?

Comment: Just a one off build. However, if the charging solution is good and universal, I would probably reuse it in some other projects, whenever I require such a battery pack

Comment: My best suggestion would be to use four floating 4.2 V CC/CV chargers, stacked in series. That will balance your batteries and charge them. Costly, but bulletproof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an expensive but simple solution:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVb8YI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'll try to tidy up this...

If you don't want to charge from mains, substitute your AC/DC charger with a DC/DC one, but isolated/floating.

Comment: You missed the live  connection on one of those.

Comment: @Hearth IE does not play along nicely with the schematics editor. I’ll fix it. Thanks!

Comment: This looks good and straightforward. Would it be possible to create multiple isolated DC voltage levels from one DC input?

Comment: @Henrik410 Yes, that’s no issue. Are you in Sweden by any chance?

Comment: No, I'm from Germay

Comment: @Henrik410 Far from price efficient for mass production, but very straight forward would be four of these followed by an TP4056 from each: https://www.ebay.de/itm/DC-DC-Converter-Isolated-Power-Supply-In-9V-18V-Out-5V/352550630213?hash=item5215a7b345:g:yUcAAOxyDgRQ-FCv